# How to check string contains comma or not in kendo UI template

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

> In kendo UI template i want to check whether string contains value with comma(',') separated or not

```html
<script id="supply-chain-manager-column-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">

    # if (UserRole != null) { #
        # if (UserRole.indexOf(',')>-1) != null) { #
    <span>#= UserRole # ...</span>
    # }  else { #
    <span>#= UserRole # ... </span>
    # } #

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This work for me**

```html
<script id="account-relationship-manager-column-template-load-management" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    # if (UserRole != null) { #
    # if (parseInt(UserRole.indexOf(',')) > 0) {#
    <a href="\#" data-bind="events: { click: onUserRoleClick }"> #= UserRole.split(',')[0] # .... </a>
    # } else { #
    <span>#= UserRole #  </span>
    # } #
    # } #
</script>
```